# How do I connect Mysql server and create database to install ExpressionEngine?

Tags: mysql, expressionengine

I am having difficulties in installing ExpressionEngine as I need a database through MySql. When I try to prep a database I get an error unless I stop the Sql server. Is this right? Shouldn't they both run together?

The Task:

Download and Install ExpressionEngine Core
Set up a new channel that uses the following content and (field types):

- Heading (text field)
- Introduction (text area)
- Image (file)
- Table of data (grid)

Set up a template that outputs your channel data to a page. You can lay it out using any design you wish. The template should include:

- At least one template embed, e.g. header or footer.
- At least one responsive breakpoint, e.g. include a desktop and mobile layout

Comment: You need to tell us what the error is.

Comment: Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306:
  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: If I do set a password, it won't recognise it, and doesn't even get to this error message... hope this makes sense

Comment: if i disconnect server, and then on work benck connect to database I get in.... then when I try to reconnect server and refresh in workbench I get this error: Could not connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)